# Trigger to prevent change to any other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good Morning Techie,

May anyone please help me to correct my below trigger.

i have two table parent and child. and i want to have 2 checks. 1st check: if searchid available in child then won't able to delete from parent. solution: i used FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES

2nd check : **if searchid available in both Parent and Child** then no column in parent table can be updated.

can anyone help me on 2nd check:

Below is the code i tried but unfortunately not working for me.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE parent
 (
     [SEARCHID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     [PACKSIZE] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
 );

 CREATE TABLE CHILD
 (
     [SEARCHID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Child_SearchId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES parent(SEARCHID),
  [glu_behav] varchar (50)
 )

 INSERT parent

 SELECT 1,1,'VODAFONE.COM','111' UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,2,'airtel.com','a213'

 insert CHILD

 SELECT 1,22,'vod.com','srt23'
```

**TRIGGER i tried**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trMyTable_Update ON parent AFTER UPDATE 

 AS

    IF not exists (select 1 from deleted)

       return

    if exists (select 1 from deleted where SEARCHID IS NOT NULL)
      AND (UPDATE(SEARCHID) OR UPDATE(SEARCHID))  -- attempt to change existing values

     begin

         raiserror('You can not change values in SEARCHID or ANYOTHER once they were saved!',16,1)

         rollback

   end
```

Thanks

Comment: Be specific about what "Not working for me" means.   Include any errors or unexpected behavior.

Comment: @TabAlleman: even Trigger present and i tried to  UPDATE parent
SET PACKSIZE = '000'
WHERE SEARCHID = '1', it should not allow, but its still allowing to update on parent table

Comment: Why shouldn't it allow it?   That update does not try to set a new value for SEACHID.

Comment: @TabAlleman: Thanks a lot.... i got my mistake instead of packsize, i added searchid twice.  Thanks again..... :)